# Regex not matching for Character

Tags: java, regex

This string contains spaces followed by DOT(`.`) and then some character. Then why regex is returning false?

```
String s="               .fds";
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\S+", s));
```

Comment: Because `matches` requires a full string match, and `\\S+` does not match leading spaces.

Comment: There are 2 things that are wrong, first of, the whitespace is a lowercase s as `\\s`. And as @WiktorStribiżew already said, `Pattern#matches` does a full `String` match, so you´d have to modify your regex in some way that the `.fds` would also be included in there.